# Using sunspot_rails with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm writing a rails app that allows people to submit links and titles a little bit like reddit.

I want to make it so that people can enter a url and find the record with a similar url. This gets tricky if people leave off the http:// at the beginning or do or don't have the trailing "/".

How do I set that up using Solr/Sunspot?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand your query properly, there are a couple of problems combined here.

You can probably use something like URI.parse(incoming_url) and then extract the relevant parts of the URL that you want. I'd then use that info and convert it to a slug using something like slugify or acts_as_slug.

I'm not sure why you want to tie that functionality into Sunspot though.